# Trajectory Optimization with Direct Transcription using Generalized Forces instead of Acutator Torques

Tags: drake

I am trying to perform trajectory optimization for a robot arm attached to a free-floating base (to simulate a spacecraft-robot arm scenario).

For the base-torque actuation, I had previously tried attaching pseudo-links with actuators to the base CoM but these approaches did not work (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093710/extra-body-with-nans-in-context-of-a-multibodyplant-causing-error-while-simulati)). In the end, I decided to use the generalized forces to control the system instead of actuators as they seem to better represent my use of space-robots (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217156/best-method-to-add-generalized-forces-to-linearized-or-lqr-multibodyplant)). For linearization, I manually change the B (actuation) matrix to include the base torque actuators (reaction wheels).

With this background, I am trying to perform trajectory optimization using Direct Transcription where I aim to find u(t) which in my case is generalized forces instead of actuator forces. I add constraints that make certain generalized forces zero (translation forces on Base CoM) to better represent the real system (reaction wheels).

Now, when I use `DirectTransciption` function for the `input_port_index` parameter I provide `input_port_index=plant.get_applied_generalized_force_input_port().get_index()` to find trajectory using generalized forces instead of actuation forces.

However, when running `Solve()`, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Actuation input port for model instance planarSC must be connected.
```

The error makes sense as indeed I do not connect the actuation input port. But the error still stays after I use `plant.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(plant.CreateDefaultContext(), np.zeros((plant.num_actuators(),1)))` to set the actuation input port to zero.

Is there a way to perform `DirectTranscription` on generalized forces as u(t) instead of the actuation forces?

Update: I've corrected the context being provided to `DirectTranscription`. The python script now has the following code but still gives the same error about not having the actuation port connected:

```
trajOptContext = plant.CreateDefaultContext()
jointAcutation =  np.zeros((plant.num_actuators(),1))
plant.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(trajOptContext, jointAcutation)

prog = DirectTranscription(plant, trajOptContext, N,
                           input_port_index=plant.get_applied_generalized_force_input_port().get_index())
```

Comment: I still think your original approach (pseudo-links with actuators) should work fine.  Using generalized forces can also work fine, and it certainly more general!  But the generalized forces input port is not vector valued -- it is expecting a data structure that is a list of forces/body/locations.  To use this with direct transcription, you would want to make another small system that takes a vector valued input and produces the generalized forces, then pass the diagram to direct transcription.

Comment: Using floating pseudo-links with floating base poses the problem that when I attach an actuator in between, the pseudo-link has infinite acceleration due to zero mass.

As for the generalized forces input port, I thought it was indeed a vector valued port as the documentation states: `Returns a constant reference to the vector-valued input port for applied generalized forces, and the vector will be added directly into tau (see System dynamics).` I have been using it until now by using a NumPy array to the port (`port.FixValue()`) for testing.

Comment: Oops.  You are correct.  I responded too quickly (and incorrectly), thinking you were using the spatial forces port. 

The problem is your line `plant.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(plant.CreateDefaultContext(), np.zeros((plant.num_actuators(),1)))`.  This will only assign the values in a newly allocated Context, which you then throw away.  You need the values to be assigned in whatever Context you pass to the optimization routine.

Comment: Ah. Indeed @Russ Tedrake. I did not see that. I tried now running the trajectory optimization while passing the same context to `DirectTransciption` that I use to fix actuation port value. However, the error saying that the actuation port must be connected is still there.